# Why is Magento not discounting my cart with the full discount amount?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I have a cart with 2 items added:

- Product 1 for £100
- Product 2 for £65

Product 2 is effectively a free gift, and to achieve this an automatic £65 discount is applied to the entire cart using a Shopping Cart Rule.

The customer is then applying a manual £20 discount from a voucher code they have.

The discount that should be applied at this point is £85 (£65 + £20), but what is actually applied is £77.12.

After a bit of number crunching it looks like Magento applies the £20 discount in a pro-rota fashion, working out the percentage that each product in the cart of the entire value is responsible for, and then applies that percentage discount of the £20 to each row individually.

In this example, it tries to apply £12.12 discount to Product 1 and £7.88 discount to product 2, which in the cart would total £20.

However, because product 2 has already been discounted by £65 Magento is not applying that £7.88 pro rota discount at all, so the cart is being discounted by an incorrect value of £77.12 (£65 + £12.12).

The £20 voucher is set up as follows:

```
Conditions: 

Subtotal >= £60.

Actions: 

Fixed amount discount for whole cart of 20. Everything else set to '0' or 'No'.
```

The automatic £65 discount is set up as follows:

```
Conditions: 

Total amount >= £95, with a sub-condition excluding some SKUs.

Actions: 

Fixed amount discount for whole cart of £65, everything else '0' or 'No'.
Apply to only: X,Y,Z SKUs
```

Answer (score 3):

So let me explain how it works first and then offer a solution.

The bug is the first rule sets the first product price to zero.  Then the second rule (whole cart discount) still substract discount from zero. Hope it will be fixed in Magento 2.

For you case I can offer to not use rule type "discount for the whole cart" at all, but use fixed amount discount for each product that is not free gift.  You can set the condition at the Actions tab (apply discount for ...)

To set free gift please also use "fixed discount" max quantity=1, not "fixed amount discount for whole cart"